# How do I quickly regain health during combat in Mass Effect: Andromeda?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

I built an Isharay with the bio-converter augmentation, which gives me an extremely powerful sniper rifle that never needs to reload (with effectively infinite ammo), but at cost of running through my health as quickly as I can take down enemies.

What options do I have to quickly replenish my health after firing a few shots with this Isharay?

I'm looking for powers, other augmentations, consumables, strategies - anything that can help. My current Ryder has primarily combat+tech skills developed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best combination you can do with the bio converter is tech skills.

Specifically, life support:

> Life Support: Improves health regeneration rate for the user and nearby squadmates and tech constructs for 3 sec after using a tech power.

```
Health Regeneration Bonus: 200%
Health Regeneration Cap: 50%
```

This will let you spam tech skills to constantly recharge your health.

Here is an example (GIF file) of someone using a bio converter Dhan with life support:

[image: animated GIF described above]

Comment: Thanks! Time for a re-spec, it seems. This looks like a good fit for a shotgun-weilder, but for a long-distance sniper... Often, when the enemies are far enough, they don't get "selected" (the name, health bar, etc., don't show), so I can't use powers on them, but the gun is still powerful enough to take them out. But, in that case, I'll probably be able to pause for a breather and let health climb back to 50%.

Comment: @muru you could also just spam skills at the floor to recharge health if you can't target anyone

Comment: I just trialled it out on the Cardinal, and it was most satisfactory. Thanks again! @Allball103 nice trick!

Comment: @muru also if you are scoped in you can still use your skills, you can sometimes snipe them at distance with it even if they're not targetable

Comment: @lI that does work for powers like concussive shot,  but for powers like Energy drain, not so much (I use these two + the Remnant VI power mostly, which leaves me without a tech power repeatedly usable without targeting )